# Why does SubItems.Clear() also delete the Name attribute?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview, listviewitem

I am using a WinForms ListView in details mode (.NET 4.0, running on Windows 7) and I have a function that needs to clear the subitems in a particular item.  Unfortunately when I do that it also clear's the name:

```
item.Name = "TESTNAME";
item.SubItems.Clear();
MessageBox.Show(item.Name); //shows nothing
```

In the debugger I've tracked it down to this, and I've looked at the [documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.listviewsubitemcollection.aspx) and it's unhelpful,

> Clear:    Removes all subitems and the parent ListViewItem from the collection.

Except the ListViewItem is still very *there* because later in the function I'm able to add SubItems to it again!

Surely I don't have to:

```
while(item.SubItems.Count > 0)
{
    item.RemoveAt(0);
}
```

Do I?

Comment: in your code sample do you mean item.Name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately `ListView` is a strange beast, and one of the strange corners of it is that its items are just a collection of values to be shown, one for each column.

The `Name` property just automates putting something into the first column, and unfortunately this "something" lives in the `SubItems` collection.

This means that if you inspect the `SubItems` collection, you'll notice that it has one element already, and after setting the name of the item, you'll see the text of that item is equal to that name.

This is the code for the [`ListViewItem.Name` property](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ListViewItem.cs.html#bc797faa212b2976):

```
public string Name {
    get {
        if (SubItemCount == 0) {
            return string.Empty;
        }
        else {
            return subItems[0].Name;
        }
    }
    set {
        SubItems[0].Name = value;
    }
}
```

And the [`ListViewSubItem.Name` property](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ListViewItem.cs.html#c1efb233a92afdf2) looks like this:

```
public string Name {
    get {
        return (name == null) ? "": name;
    }
    set {
        name = value;
        if (owner != null) {
            owner.UpdateSubItems(-1);
        }
    }
}
```

So, clearing the `SubItems` collection has the consequence of clearing the properties of that first item, as you've discovered, in addition to removing every other item from the collection.

Actually, what happens is that the collection is cleared, but any attempt to look at the `SubItems` collection while it is empty will create a new collection with one item, with default property values. In the above example code, reading the `SubItems` collection will [automagically assign a collection with one item](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ListViewItem.cs.html#c727e4759bcb95b2) to the internal field, if the collection isn't already there.

So yes, this is how it "works".

In fact, to remove every subitem except the first, your loop would have to be:

```
while (item.SubItems.Count > 1)
    item.SubItems.RemoveAt(1);
```

Comment: Once another 6 minutes has passed I'll accept.
Wow, strange beast is right, I tried to find documentation that would explain this, does it exist?

Comment: Not entirely sure, let me try as well.

Comment: See @Matt's [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4097912/why-does-subitems-clear-also-delete-the-name-attribute/4098020#4098020).

Answer (score 3):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.subitems.aspx):

> **Note**
>
> The first subitem in the
>   ListViewItem.ListViewSubItemCollection
>   is always the item that owns the
>   subitems. When performing operations
>   on subitems in the collection, be sure
>   to reference index position 1 instead
>   of 0 to make changes to the first
>   subitem.

Thus, clearing the sub items collection, clears the values for the parent as well.

Comment: Link added to the MSDN word in the first line.

Answer (score 0):

**Please note 1:**
The `ListViewItem.Text` (not the `Name`) is the `ListViewItem.SubItems[0]`, **but:**
the `ListViewItem.SubItems.Clear()` **clears also the `ListViewItem.Name`!**

So, if you use `SubItems.Clear`, you then have to restore both `Name` and `Text` (if you need them).

**Please note 2:**
If you use `*Key` methods (eg. `ListView.Items.ContainsKey()` or `ListView.Items.RemoveByKey()`) to access the items (instead of `*Index` ones), take care of the `ListViewItem.Name`, which is the `key` you need to pass to these methods...

What a smart logic...

For the case anyone is forced or wants to use `ListView` I have discovered another problem described in [question 23007388](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23007388/listview-does-not-show-images-after-switching-view-mode).

*As it might take very long time to determine all this stuff, I have posted this answer even this thread is a little bit old.*