# ListView does not show images after switching view mode

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

When I add item(s) to the `ListView` in any other than `LargeIcon` view mode, the `ListView` stops showing the images from `LargeImageList` when it is switched back to `LargeIcon`. This situation lasts until new item is added to the `ListView` in the `LargeIcon` mode.

So the following sequence illustrates the problem:

1. create `ListView`, add column, set `View` to `Details`
2. create `ImageList`, set `ImageSize`, assign it to `ListView.LargeImageList`
3. create new `ListViewItem`, set its `ImageKey`
4. create new image, add it to the `ImageList` with given key
5. add the `ListViewItem` to the `ListView`
6. switch the `ListView` mode to `LargeIcon`

   - **no images are shown**
7. repeat steps #3 - #6, now in the `LargeIcon` mode

   - **all images are shown as expected**

**What is the point I am still missing?**

I have tried following:

- Invalidate the `ListView`
- Re-assign the `LargeImageList` before/after adding the item (even through `null`)

The test code for those who like it more than words:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int       counter = 0;
    ImageList iList   = new ImageList();

    private string GetNewKey()
    {
        return counter++.ToString();
    }

    private Image GetNewImage(Size size)
    {
        var bmp = new Bitmap(size.Width, size.Height);

        using (var gra = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
        {
            var rnd = new Random();

            var lines = rnd.Next(1000);

            for (int l = 0; l < lines; ++l)
            {
                var pen = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(rnd.Next(256), rnd.Next(256), rnd.Next(256)));
                var p1  = new Point(rnd.Next(size.Width), rnd.Next(size.Height)); 
                var p2  = new Point(rnd.Next(size.Width), rnd.Next(size.Height));
                gra.DrawLine(pen, p1, p2);
            }
        }

        return bmp;
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        iList.ImageSize         = new Size(100, 100);
        listView.LargeImageList = iList;
        listView.Columns.Add("name");
    }

    private void buttonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var key = GetNewKey();
        var lvi = new ListViewItem()
        {
            Name     = key,
            Text     = "blabla",
            ImageKey = key,
        };

        iList.Images.Add(key, GetNewImage(new Size(100, 100)));
        listView.Items.Add(lvi);
    }

    private void buttonClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listView.Items.Clear();
    }

    private void buttonLarge_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listView.View = View.LargeIcon;
    }

    private void buttonDetails_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listView.View = View.Details;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

For anyone who would suffer the same problem. After some experiments, there is at least stupid poor man's workaround:

Modify the `ImageList`, the `ListView` **somehow** detects its change and reloads the images for `LargeIcon` mode. The questions are **how** it detects the change and **why** does it ignore the `ImageList` after mode change...

```
    private void FixIt()
    {
        // Trigger a reload of the ListView.LargeImageList
        if (listView.View == View.LargeIcon)
        {
            var key = "Dummy image to be deleted right after its insertion...";
            iList.Images.Add(key, new Bitmap(1, 1));
            iList.Images.RemoveByKey(key);            
        }
    }
```

**EDIT #2:**
I have also discovered some other funny features the `ListView` and associated components have. You might want to check them in answers of [question 4097912](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4097912/why-does-subitems-clear-also-delete-the-name-attribute) and [question 23059678](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23059678/imagelist-strange-behaviour-ater-changing-imagesize)

Comment: I think you didn't set the SmallImageList to an image list, check it please

Comment: Right, I didn't. I didn't want small icons, just either large ones or text (details). Is the SmallImageList needed for proper work of LargeIcon mode?

Answer (score 1):

**To solve your problem**

You could avoid this by useing `ImageIndex` instead of `ImageKey` to connect your `ListView` with the `ImageList`. So in your `buttonAdd_Click` event use:

```
  var lvi = new ListViewItem()
        {
            Name     = key,
            Text     = "blabla",
            //ImageKey = key,
            //Use ImageIndex and don't set both
            ImageIndex= Convert.ToInt32(key) //you could just use count++ 
        };
```

**The reason behind this problem:**

The reason behind this is not clear to me, but I assume this may be a bug that when changing from `Details` to `LargeIcon`, it only checks `ImageIndex` in default and if you set `ImageKey` the `ImageIndex` will be set to `-1`. Or may be this is by design, I don't know (see `ImageKey` section below), since you don't have a `SmallImageList`, so when changing to `LargeIcon` view, `ImageIndex` is `null` or `-1` and the `ImageKey` is ignored.

**About [ListViewItem.ImageIndex Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.imageindex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)**

> The ImageKey and ImageIndex properties are mutually exclusive, meaning if one is set, the other is ignored. Furthermore, if you set the ImageKey property, the ImageIndex property is automatically set to -1. Alternatively, if you set the ImageIndex property, the ImageKey is automatically set to an empty string ("").

**About [ListViewItem.ImageKey Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.imagekey%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)**

> If you are using multiple image lists, for small and large icon view, with a ListView control, you should place small and large versions of the image at the same index location in their respective image lists. ***When switching between views, the index location of the image in one list is used to locate the image in the other list, regardless of the key value specified.***

And this can somehow be verified:

- using your existing code (use `ImageKey`)
- set `ImageIndex` for any `Item` in your `listView` within the `buttonLarge_Click` event handler will show you that item's image.
- set `ImageKey` for any `Item` within the `buttonLarge_Click` event handler will not show that itme's image.

e.g.:

```
 private void buttonLarge_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listView.View = View.LargeIcon;
            //Set ImageIndex of Item 0 you could see its Icon.
            listView.Items[0].ImageIndex= 0 ;

            //set ImageKey will change nothing 
            //listView.Items[0].ImageKey= "0" ; 
        }
```

Comment: Nice, thanks. The problem with the index is following: any time you delete an item from the ListView, you have to rebuild the indices, otherwise you get wrong images assigned to the ListView items...

Comment: @sharpener, I suppose you mean any time you delete an item from the `ImageList`, you have to rebuild the indices?

Comment: If you delete an item from the `ListView` you don't need to delete it associated image from `ImageList`, so you don't need to rebuild anything.

Comment: Right, I meant also the ImageList maintenance. In the case the ListView content is little dynamic and you make thousands of item deletions/insertions, but no deletion in the ImageList, the memory consumption for ImageList might exceed reasonable range...

Comment: @sharpener, will you be able to just `Dispose()` image from `ImageList` rather than to delete it to remain the index and release memory?

Comment: Might be... Probably it could be enough to set the image to null (in the case the ImageList also as ListView wouldn't complain). Anyway I consider this as the worse workaround than the one with ImageList update.

Comment: @sharpener, sure, it's up to you. But I don't think you will be able to assign `null` to the image, and that's why I suggested you to use `Dispose()`..